# How to call a dismissBlock property on a pushed view controller?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have two view controllers, both inside a navigation controller. The parent controller a table view, and I set up delegation correctly for the table view. When I tap a row on the parent view controller, I want the child controller to appear. This works, that is the child view controller appears, and I have a "back" navigation button on the child controller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Create and push another view controller.
    ChildVC *detailVC = [[ChildVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChildVC" bundle:nil];

    // When user dismisses child controller do this...
    [detailVC setDismissBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"Dismiss block called");
    }];

    // Setup navigation
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
}
```

In ChildVC.h I have

```
@interface ChildVC : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^dismissBlock)(void);
@end
```

In ChildVC.m I have the following to try to execute the parent controller's dismiss block code, but to no avail, that is, I don't see the NSLog executed.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if (![[self.navigationController viewControllers] containsObject:self]) {
        // We were removed from the navigation controller's view controller stack
        // thus, we can infer that the back button was pressed
        **// How do I call the presenting controller's dissmissBlock?**
        **// I tried the following to no avail, since presentingViewController is nil**
        [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:_dismissBlock];
    }
}
```

If using a dismiss block is not the mechanism here, what is? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of an anti-pattern as your Child View Controllers should know nothing about their Parents in general...  But to address your current issue - you're calling the dismiss block in viewWillDisappear - and your test for whether your view controller is still on the stack will return YES - since the view has not disappeared yet.

Another problem is that the 'back' navigation button, assuming it's the standard UINavigationController back button, is already calling the dismissViewControllerAnimated: method, and so even if you changed this to viewDidDisappear, by the time you call `[self presentingViewController]' it will be nil.

It sounds like you want to do something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    if (![[self.navigationController viewControllers] containsObject:self]) {
        if (_dismissBlock) _dismissBlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling the _dismissBlock() function did the trick. I forget that this is just a function.